# Configure shipping methods for Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, shipping-methods

This is driving me crazy - I've used different CMS and eCommerce platforms in the past and they seemed so much easier to deal with.

So, my website (Magento 1.8) is setup with products and I offer two delivery options to all products: Next Day Delivery (£4.00) and Free Delivery (3-5 working days). I've set that up which is working great as it allows the customer to choose the delivery method.

I now have a product which I need to charge £3.00 for delivery and exclude them from the two shipping methods mentioned above, but I can't seem to be able to find a way to do this. I can't find a way to add new Shipping methods for example which I've done previously with other platforms.

Any ideas?

Kind regards
Liam

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do this without writing a shipping carrier, or using an extension to meet your needs here. Out of the box Magento offers pretty basic shipping and has no product based capabilities.